# What options do I have to finish up/trim these edges of my tiling?

Tags: tile

For this picture
[image]

#1,#2 I am not sure if I want to go up to the ceiling since the ceiling is not level :-( That is something that I missed. Is it an option to go level with the tiles up to the lowest point and then to try to mud the ceiling to make it join the tiles level ? If this is not an option what options do I have ? Aluminium edging ? Bull nose tiles matching the tiles I have ? If I go to close to the ceiling that is going to accentuate the ceiling error. If I go to low I will leave too much drywall exposed to the water in the shower area

#3 on this edge do I need any trimming or it is enough to finish the tiles 1/8" close to the perpendicular wall and grout that ?

#4 this will be a grout line, I don't think anything else is recommended here

#5 outside corner -should I miter or should I use aluminum?

#6 #7 do I need a trim here ? I don't think so but I am just asking to make sure
the exposed edges of the tile near the window will get covered by the window trimming (the window is white vinyl set in a plywood frame)

#8 #9 #10 not sure what to do here
The wall is cinder block, internal wall dry like a bone. The drywall sits straight on it nothing in between (screwed with tapcons)
My initial plan was to set this flush with the drywall and avoid any finishing on the #8 and #9 edges but then I realized that I will have a problem at #10 as there will be a tile baseboard made of the same tile as the floor. I can't set the tile baseboard flush with the drywall either because that will force me to do that all around the room and in some places it is not possible

So what would you do here ?

Update:
here is how much my ceiling is out of level and where, across the 1 and 2 edges. All the lines are straight though even if they are not level
[image]

Comment: Does the drawing reflect the size tiles you are using? How far off level is the ceiling? Stopping short of the ceiling may show that it's off level. If you tile up to the ceiling and the grout line is far enough from the ceiling you won't notice it being un-level.

Comment: yes the tiles are 24x24 (nominal 23.60")

Comment: How about an actual picture of what you've done so far.

Comment: Ceiling not level, what do you mean?  Is one end higher or is it in waves.  If in a straight line, just cut tiles to fit.

Comment: Did you start your tiles from the bottom - that is, the lip of the tub?  If so, that might be part of the problem as tubs may be installed on a slight slope towards the drain.  At least my old cast iron tub is.

Comment: Did you consider using some small crown molding to finish off the wall/ceiling joint?

Comment: And on #4, (I know there are varying opinions on this) I used a silicone sealant for the corner joints when I tiled around the bathtub.

Comment: @jack there is nothing to see just cement boards on the wall

Comment: Why aren't you actually doing the project? We're not a discussion  forum. You've asked many questions and have done nothing. This is a DIY site, not a design site...

Comment: ?? Not sure what your problem is ...I just finished the floor https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/238212/how-do-i-use-the-4-screws-not-the-bolts-that-come-with-the-flange-extender-whe  you can see tiles around the toilet flange here for example so I am making progress, I just don't post pictures with the results here

Comment: I don't have a problem. Your problem is you'd get better answers if you did the work up to the point where you have a concern, then take a picture and ask the question.  You'd eliminate the "I need to see" answers.

Comment: ok good then. Sorry but I prefer to understand and have a clear picture of what I am going to execute ...hence the question

Comment: Re #10 the "plinth" ... what is that?   Is it like a baseboard, or is it something much larger, like a tiled box covering some pipes, or something like that?

Comment: I think parts of this question like finished-edge-vs-metal-strip are 100% design questions and if you reduce the size of the question to where there are real problems, you'll get more enthusiastic answers and less flak.  Your #8 and #10, where you have tile flush with drywall with an irregularity at the bottom .... that's interesting.

Comment: Interesting option but not feasible due to the edging problem (I call it plinth but I think it is called tile baseboard)

Comment: I have added info regarding the ceiling and how much it is off level

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2 Tile up to the ceiling. My ceiling is off by 1/2" over 4'and it's not noticeable. If you stop short it will be noticeable. If you have a horizontal grout line close to the ceiling it will be noticeable. With 24" tile, and proper layout you should not have a grout line close to the ceiling. #3 tile close to the wall and caulk (not grout), you can get caulk to match the grout. #4 same as #3. #5 do a search for Schluter Outside Corner, Schluter is a brand there's others. #6 & #7 I'd need to see what you plan to do for trim but putting the trim over the edge of the tile should be fine. #8 & #9 Use a Schluter (or other brand) edge. #10 I'd need to see what "plinth" you are using. If by plinth you mean base trim just butt it against the Schluter edge which should go all the way down to the floor.

Comment: #7 and #8 are inside corners ..do I need any trim there ? The wet tile saw I have (a Ridgid)   is fantastic, When I did the floor I was lucky I put some marks on the tiles (painter tape with numbers and orientation) otherwise I was not able to say which was the factory edge and which was the cut. So having such good cuts ..do I need a trim there ? I thought I would I ask but the plan was to put on the wall the large 17"tiles behind the toilet and then hide the  cuts by installing the side tiles

Comment: Re: grout line next to the ceiling -I think it is a matter of terminology ...Before your comment I would call grout line any line between the edge of a tile and something close to it, within 1/8" distance so for instance that is what I call line 3 and 4  and I would call 1 and 2 the same way if the tile goes all  the way up to the ceiling, 1/8" close to it and I would fill the space with mud probably. I think the pros call grout line any line between two adjacent tiles.
I am confused regarding 4 and the need to use caulking there instead of just grout. Why is that (not saying it is not right)

Comment: 1 and 2 you would tile all the way to the ceiling and caulk where the tile meets the ceiling. If it's wavy and not straight where the tile meets the ceiling then you should level the ceiling with joint compound before tiling. If the ceiling is straight but not level that will be noticeable if your top row of tiles are thin and your next row of tiles are close to the ceiling. 3 and 4 should be caulked. Grout doesn't hold up well in corners that's why you use caulk.

Comment: I see what you mean, so  you are saying that the last (top) row of tiles must be as much as possible close to a full tile in order to make things less obvious (because the reference line -the top of the next raw of times- must be as low as possible. Makes sense. I did consider that too. I take it that adding mud to the ceiling and painting over would be a weird option. I will add a picture to explain the uneven ceiling problem

Comment: C to the corner is fine. You should mud A to B so you have a straight line from A to the corner. Although if it's less than 1/2" over 30" - 40" it may not be noticeable.